# Kivy: Change popup title label proprieties

Tags: python, properties, kivy, popup, title

I'm writing an interface with Kivy.
I've added a change in my .kv file that remove size_hint from Label

```
<Label>
    size_hint: None, None
```

This change reflects itself obviously on all labels, included the labels of all buttons and, my problem, the label of the popup title.

In fact, label of the popup title remains little and text goes to newline after few letters (you can see it easily by creating a popup with a long title and set the Label with size_hint: None, None)

I could write a custom class like MyLabel@Label but this will not reflects on all buttons, and I should rewrite all buttons, and all place where labels are used but not explicitly declared by the code.

That's why I'm looking for another way to accomplish this.

There's a way to tell to kivy, in .kv file or in my python main.py, to use a different label class for my popup title? or to set the size_hint property of the label used in the popup title?

Thanks for Your Attention,
Best Regards.

[EDIT]

[Screenshot of the running example problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNzid.png)

Example:

my.kv

```
<Label>
    size_hint: None, None
```

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window

def ForceLimit():
    pop = Popup(title='Force limit reached!',content=Label(text='Force limit reached! Decremental movement inhibited.'),size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #Window.borderless = True
        Window.size = (1024,600)
        return ForceLimit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: kivy.clock.ClockPlease post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.